# Controller Without Classes

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm new to this TypeScript thing. There are a bunch of examples of using Angular with Typescript, and they all have controller classes. It looks like I have to repeat the injected services a number of times in the class declaration. Can I create an Angular controller without creating a class? Preferably something like what I could do with JavaScript:

```
module.controller('controller', function(service1) {DoSomething();});
```

Comment: Any JavasScript code is also valid TS code. So anything you would write in JS you can write in TS aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you want to (since valid js is valid ts). But you will lose the type safety of classes.